# Why no dropdownd here?

Tags: asp.net

How come there is no dropdown on the top three classes? Just created them, code structure id fine.

I also cannot access them from other classes.

All of them are public, and the properties are public as well. They contain no methods, just properties.

[image]

Comment: without seeing the content of the files it's impossible to say. Perhaps they don't have any classes in them, or there are errors in the code. Who knows.

Comment: have you tried Rebuilding the project ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You can also try closing the `VS` and running it again. Delete the entire `bin` and `obj` folder. They will come back with your next build. Also delete the hidden `vs` folder to delete `.suo` file which have `intellisense`. Your classes are not being read by `intellisense` that is why they are unavailable and simply dont exist.

Secondly, plus `+` sign means you need to add the item or its newly added and is not yet checked in.

Comment: There is no "Add" option when I right click, only Exclude From Project and some others.

Comment: No the plus sign means they haven't been checked into source control yet

Comment: Whether the item is checked in to source control or not has no relationship to the question being asked, though. OP is asking about the dropdownlist of classes, not the plus sign.

Comment: That's probably closer to the answer, yes - as I pointed out in my comment without seeing the contents we can't be sure the code would even produce this UI from intellisense, but equally it could be a problem with intellisense. Difficult to be certain. P.S. the bit about the plus sign is still irrelevant and can be removed.

Comment: @ADyson agreed. Without seeing the class structure it will remain a mystery. May be it will help the OP to get into some direction.